# How to get text from html tag span through Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

Here is my HTML  and trying to get the text **must be unique.** with Python 2.7

[image: my image html]

Tried to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='lblError']/text()")
```

The xpath was not valid one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`enter code here`time.sleep(1)
`enter code here`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='lblError']")
`enter code here`text = element.text

Answer (score 0):

try to find the element by ID then get_attribute("innerHTML").

```
var el = driver.find_element_by_id("lblerror")
var text = el.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: I am using python, above code seems to be for java. I have tried to use: text = driver.find_element_by_id("lblError") and that error out.

Comment: first, your snippet is wrong.   look in the python webdriver docs https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you for reference link but my snippet is not wrong. I will attach a whole thing.

Comment: I didn't write " text = driver.find_element_by_id("lblError")" which you show as an error

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the text **must be unique** you can use the `execute_script()` method and you can use the following solution:

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='lblError']")
myText = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).strip()
```

Comment: The below did not work, it seems to be invalid path :myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='lblError']")

Comment: Hmm, _invalid path_, I took the reference from your code trials and the snapshot of the HTML you have provided. Can you update the question with the text based relevant HTML? As you are using **pyhton 2.7** remember to append **self** before the applicable one.